# Cannot print object repr using __repr__ in Python

Tags: python, class, import, repr

This is my directory's structure:

[image]

This is the `declaration.py` code:

```
class Declaration:

    def __init__(self, prop, prop_value):
        self.prop = prop
        self.prop_value = prop_value

    def __repr__(self):
        str = f'{self.prop}: {self.prop_value}'
        return str
```

This is the `main.py` code:

```
from structure.declaration import Declaration

dec = Declaration('color', 'red')

print(dec)
```

When I run the `main.py` file, I get:

```
<structure.declaration.Declaration object at 0x03992748>
```

Instead of expected output:

```
color: red
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: As mentioned already, the issue is not reproducible, see here: https://ideone.com/vjjDP0. not sure if there could be any difference due to the directory structure which I highly doubt.

Comment: Are you sure you have saved the file before running it.

Comment: yes, in the same file it working for me too. But in this directory strcuture it does not. Yes, all the files are saved before running.